# How do I handle VueJS error handling with vue-error-boundary

Tags: javascript, error-handling, vuejs3

Recently I came across [vue-error-boundary](https://github.com/dillonchanis/vue-error-boundary) which I like the idea of very much and would like to implement it into my own projects.

I want to use vue-error-boundary features to load a component with an error instead of crashing my app. However for some reason all I can do is get the `on-error` prop to work, component GETS loaded but with a warning and the App still Crushes.

For Reproduction purpose:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blank-vue-tailwind-testing-vue-error-boundary-dl4r7l?file=/src/components/ImUnstable.vue)

I get following error:

```
Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <ImUnstable> 
  at <VErrorBoundary on-error=fn<bound TriggerMe> fall-back= 
{render: ƒ render(), __hmrId: "6505c1f8", __file: "src/components/ContactError.vue"}
>
```

CODE:

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <VErrorBoundary :on-error="TriggerMe" :fall-back="fallBack">
    <ImUnstable />
  </VErrorBoundary>
</template>

<script>
import { markRaw } from "vue";
import VErrorBoundary from "vue-error-boundary";
import ImUnstable from "@/components/ImUnstable.vue";
import ContactError from "@/components/ContactError";
export default {
  components: {
    ImUnstable,
    VErrorBoundary,
  },
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      fallBack: markRaw(ContactError),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    TriggerMe() {
      console.log("It Triggered");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

ImUnstable.vue:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
    <p>
      {{ user.name }}
      {{ makeLarge(user.surname) }}
      {{ user.age }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  errorCaptured() {
    console.log("let me see");
  },
  data() {
    return {
      users: [
        { id: 1, name: "Luke", surname: "Skywalker", age: "22" },
        { id: 2, name: "Han", surname: {}, age: "35" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    makeLarge(data) {
      return data.toUpperCase();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

ContactError.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>There was an issue obtaining contact's information.</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I've looked closely at what you have and it appears that, although you implemented the plugin precisely as specified in the provided documentation, the plugin doesn't deliver on its promise. It doesn't eat errors. I suggest you raise this with the plugin author, using github issues. To be fair, I don't fully understand what type of help are you expecting from developers other than the plugin author. Forking and fixing the package?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will raise an issue on GitHub

Comment: For what it's worth, I confirm I haven't spotted anything on your part which might have caused the plugin not to work (and I pay attention to details). Except for `import`s of Vue components without the `.vue` filename, which is required. But I fixed that and the plugin still doesn't work.